# Laravel: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, bulma, buefy

I'm following the tutorial form [DevMarketer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEjrUCEN3WY) and got lost when `Vue commands`

dont work on my codes. I run `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` to generate the errors but, nothing happens seems like my code is totally working then i check on `developer tool` on my browser then the error pops up comming from `root`.

The error message is:
[Vue warn]: Property or method "password_options" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

And this is the breakdown:

```
warn                        @   app.js:sourcemap:32590
warnNonPresent              @   app.js:sourcemap:33896
has                         @   app.js:sourcemap:33929
(anonymous)                 @   VM8162:2
Vue._render                 @   app.js:sourcemap:36541
updateComponent             @   app.js:sourcemap:34785
get                         @   app.js:sourcemap:35139
Watcher                     @   app.js:sourcemap:35128
mountComponent              @   app.js:sourcemap:34792
Vue.$mount                   @  app.js:sourcemap:40537
Vue.$mount                   @  app.js:sourcemap:42936
Vue._init                   @   app.js:sourcemap:36637
Vue                         @   app.js:sourcemap:36726
(anonymous)                 @   app.js:sourcemap:988
__webpack_require__         @   app.js:sourcemap:20
Object.defineProperty.value @   app.js:sourcemap:969
__webpack_require__         @   app.js:sourcemap:20
(anonymous)                 @   app.js:sourcemap:63
(anonymous)                 @   app.js:sourcemap:66
```

dev tool vue error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

<div class="management-area" id="app" style="position: absolute;top: 4rem;left: 200px;right: 0;">
        <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="columns m-t-10">
        <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title">Edit User</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <h1 class="m-t-0"></h1>
            <form action="http://localhost/cnb/public/manage/users/3" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="poLNMotZhSoaEG7NH4WJZPoQKTAsGGy47462aM9J">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
                    <p class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" value="User">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                    <p class="control">
                        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="user@app.com">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <b-radio-grou>
                    <div class="field" v-model="password_options">
                        <b-radio value="keep">Do Not Change Password</b-radio>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <b-radio value="auto">Auto-Generate New Password</b-radio>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <b-radio value="manual">Manually Set New Password</b-radio>
                        <p class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password" v-if="password_options == 'manual'" placeholder="Manually give a password to this user" required="">
                        </p>
                    </div>   
                    </b-radio-grou>           
                </div>  
                <button class="button is-primary">Edit User</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

- <div v-model="password_options">: v-model is not supported on this element type. If you are working with contenteditable, it's recommended to wrap a library dedicated for that purpose inside a custom component.
```

Component code:

```
require('./bootstrap')

window.Vue = require('vue')
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(Buefy.default);

var app = new Vue({ 
    el:'#app', 
    data:{ auto_password:true } 
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            password_options: ''
        }
    }
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hover(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you looked at the given link in the error message? Whats unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the model to a div, which only works for inputs, if you want to only show or hide the div, change the v-model to `v-if`

```
<div class="management-area" id="app" style="position: absolute;top: 4rem;left: 200px;right: 0;">
    <div class="flex-container">
<div class="columns m-t-10">
    <div class="column">
        <h1 class="title">Edit User</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
        <h1 class="m-t-0"></h1>
        <form action="{{route('users.update', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
                <p class="control">
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                <p class="control">
                    <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="password_options">
                    <div class="field">
                        <b-form-checkbox value="keep">Do Not Change Password</b-form-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <b-form-checkbox value="auto">Auto-Generate New Password</b-form-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <b-form-checkbox value="manual">Manually Set New Password</b-form-checkbox>
                        <p class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password" v-if="password_options == 'manual'" placeholder="Manually give a password to this user" required>
                        </p>
                    </div>   
                </b-radio-group>           
            </div>  
            <button class="button is-primary">Edit User</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i refresh my browser the the data under the password_option is show for a (ms) then it went out

Comment: Can you download https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd and tell me the data that is being set

Comment: i edited my question see the please see the root error

Comment: v-model is for inputs, change v-model to v-if

Comment: sorry my mistake i already change <b-radio-grou> to <b-radio-group> and my <b-radio> still dont work

Comment: when i changed it to v-if its gone again

Comment: Don't use v-model on that div for what you're trying to achieve thats your error

Comment: i used v-if then the radio buttons are gone

Comment: Updated, try again

Comment: I tried to transfer it to another pc but still dont work

Comment: when i click the button they can activate at the same time and cannot be deactivated

Comment: Yes, you need to add javascript to uncheck it, or use a checkbox instead... check updated answer